# Removing start and end <br> tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Quick question:

What's the best way to go about removing `<br>` and `<br />` tags from the start and end of a `$string`?

I'm currently using this code, but it doesn't appear to remove just `<br>` tags.

```
$str = preg_replace('{^(<br(\s*/)?>|ANDnbsp;)+}i', '', $str);
$str = preg_replace('{(<br(\s*/)?>|ANDnbsp;)+$}i', '', $str);
```

---

**EDIT: Additional Information**

This code is dealing with information that has been imported from an old CMS.

As such, I *know* that the only two tags I need to replace are `<br>` and `<br />`. Additionally, I am *only looking to replace these tags at the very beginning and very end of a `$string`, not in between*.

I don't need to deal with any other tags; malformed HTML nor additional attributes.

Essentially I would simply like to expand the code I have suggested so that the `<br>` tags are replaced as well as `<br />`.

I apologise for not offering enough information to begin with.

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You regexes are working nice for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility of regex is this:

```
"/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/"
```

So let's make it clearer:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(^)?(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+$/", "", $str);
```

Explaining:

- * - Match 0 or more times;
- \s - Matches any whitespace character;
- ? - Match 0 or 1 times; or: shortest match;
- ^ - Matches only in the beginning of the string;
- $ - Matches only in the end of the string;

A good starting point: [Regular expressions in Perl](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I'm awful at regex. Could you explain how your regex works? Why does my code have `?>` in it where yours doesn't?

Comment: Would not match `<br class="fail"/>`, for example.

Comment: This will remove all the `<br>`, not only the ones at the begining and at the end of the string.

Comment: I have updated my original post. Can this be amended to only work at the start of the string?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can now match only tags that are in the start and end of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Thou shall not use Regex to parse html.

If you get a regex that matches `<br />` and `<br>`, what happens if someone throws in a `style`, `class`, or `id`? If you write that, what if they throw in a title? or just put in some badly formatted code?

You should use a function like `strip_tags()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Or a DOM parser [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Comment: How does your DOM parser handle malformed or extremely badly formatted code? Probably worse than your average regex, I'm guessing? strip_tags doesn't do what he wants to do, as it removes *every* tag, not just line-endings.

You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse HTML, but please just stay a little pragmatic? Sometimes, bad practices are the best practices and blindly shouting pseudo-biblical lines isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: And I'm sorry that you've been my target of choice, but I get sick of people prescribing medicine if they don't know all the symptoms.

Comment: *"How does your DOM parser handle malformed or extremely badly formatted code?"* -- better than most regex would.

Comment: strip_tags() allows you to include allowed tags, and by default a dom parser is going to handle normal cases better than a maintainable regex. That said, `preg_replace()` might be the way to go, it depends on the user's situation. As a general rule, though, I try to give best practice in my answers.

Comment: Hi gents, I'm going to update my original post with some further information. My mistake for not being specific enough.